# How do I display object I get from public_tweets = api.home_timeline() in My Django app?

Tags: python, django, api, twitter, tweepy

EDIT I'm new to this so excuse me for not knowing much, I Just started messing with tweepy in my django app. I want to pull in objects from

```
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
```

and display them in my django template. I tried doing this

```
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'jk'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'op'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'o-'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'jo'


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user('raso0')

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

context = {
    "tweets": public_tweets
    }
```

and In my templateI did

```
{{tweets}}
```

and also

```
 {% for t in tweets %}
  {{t}}
 {% endfor %}
```

neither of those worked though. My ultimate goal is to pull the the top hashtags in twitter and the users connected to them. But primarily to get the top hash tags the users are secondary any help on how to make this work would be great.

EDIT:

if I do

```
print(public_tweets)
```

It returns

```
 [Status(_json={{'coordinates': None, 'favorited': False, 
    'user': {
        'profile_background_color': '6789DE', 
        'profile_background_image_url_https': 
        'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000159753674/h4JqIjyc.jpeg', 
        'has_extended_profile': False, 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'FAF2E5', 
        'profile_background_tile': True, 
        'entities': 
            {'url': {
                'urls': [{
                    'indices': [0, 23], 
                    'url': 'https:///9M00f0rXzB', 
                    'display_url': 'UnivisionNoticias.com', 
                    'expanded_url': 'http://www.UnivisionNoticias.com'
                }]}, 
                'description': {'urls': [{'indices': [91, 114], 
                'url': 'https:///RNbRYjgZKb', 
                'display_url': 'uni.vi/STMDp', 
                'expanded_url': 'http://uni.vi/STMDp'}, 
                {'indices': [127, 150], 
                'url': 'https://De6i7jhLnU', 
                'display_url': 'uni.vi/STMKO', 
                'expanded_url': 
                'http://uni.vi/STMKO'}]}}, 
                'id': 35785401, 
                'statuses_count': 119247, 
                'listed_count': 6295, 
                'profile_banner_url': 
                'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/35785401/1459357894', 
                'profile_image_url': 
                'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/715644463947776002/pO5EZh4S_normal.jpg', 
                'contributors_enabled': False, 
                'protected': False, 
                'default_profile': False, 
                'notifications': False, 
                'favourites_count': 4856, 'profile_text_color': '031441', 
                'profile_background_image_url': 
                'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000159753674/h4JqIjyc.jpeg', 
                'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'FFFFFF', 'geo_enabled': True, 'default_profile_image': False, 
                'created_at': 'Mon Apr 27 16:29:42 +0000 2009', 'name': 'Univision Noticias', 'time_zone': 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', 
                'id_str': '35785401', 'profile_image_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/715644463947776002/pO5EZh4S_normal.jpg', 
                'verified': True, 'url': 'https://9M00f0rXzB', 'is_translation_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 
                'follow_request_sent': False, 'followers_count': 1425477, 'location': 'Estados Unidos', 'friends_count': 1669, 
                'description': 'Noticias de la comunidad hispana y el acontecer mundial, al instante. Síguenos en Facebook https://RNbRYjgZKb e Instagram https:///De6i7jhLnU', 
                'profile_link_color': 'CB201D', 'screen_name': 'UniNoticias', 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'following': True, 'lang': 'es', 
                'utc_offset': -14400}, 'place': None, 'entities': {'media': [{'sizes': {'medium': {'h': 675, 'resize': 'fit', 'w': 1200},
```

how can I display this data in my template?

neither of those worked though. My ultimate goal is to pull the the top hashtags in twitter and the users connected to them. But primarily to get the top hash tags the users are secondary any help on how to make this work would be great.

Comment: Your printed data is misding it's beginning which is important to determine the data structure's type(s).

Comment: I got it to display I had a typo in my code I was missing one curly bracket.   {{twitter}but how do I parse it? the info above?